# Python3. Classes, Inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

```
...
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class UserInfoModalWindow(QDialog): 
    def init(self):                                
        super(UserInfoModalWindow, self).init() 
        self.dialog_window = QDialog(self) 
        ... 
        self.dialog_window.exec_() 
        ... 
    def quit(self): 
        self.dialog_window.close()

...

class AcceptDialogWindow(UserInfoModalWindow):
    def init(self):
        super(UserInfoModalWindow, self).init() 
        self.accept_dialog = QDialog()
        ...
        self.accept_button = QPushButton()
        self.cancel_button = QPushButton()
        ... 
        self.connect(self.accept_button, 
                     SIGNAL('clicked()'), 
                     lambda: self.quit()) 
        self.connect(self.cancel_button, 
                     SIGNAL('clicked()'), 
                     self.accept_dialog.close)
        ... 
        self.accept_dialog.exec_() 
    ... 
    # From this method I want to call a method from a parent class 
    def quit(self): 
        self.accept_dialog.close() 
        return super(UserInfoModalWindow, self).quit()
```

When clicked 'cancel_button' - only accept_dialog closes, that's right,
however when clicked 'accept_button' - accept_dialog AND dialog_window should be closed.

```
I get this error: File "app.py", line 252, in quit
return super(UserInfoModalWindow, self).quit() 
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'quit'
```

What is the issue? What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're using a Python 2 way of doing things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
return super(UserInfoModalWindow, self).quit()
```

You want:

```
return super(AcceptDialogWindow, self).quit()
```

`super()` first argument is supposed to be the current class (for most use case at least).  Actually `super(cls, self).method()` means:

- get the mro of `self`
- locate class `cls` in the mro
- take the *next* class (the one after `cls`)
- execute the method from this class

So `super(UserInfoModalWindow, self)` in `AcceptDialogWindow` resolves to the parent of  `UserInfoModalWindow`, which is `QDialog`.

Note that in Python 3.x, you don't have to pass any argument to `super()` - it will automagically do the RightThing(tm).

Comment: You should probably mention plain no arg `super()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.